# How to create exclusive list of CSV entries in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
Category,Value
category1,162
category1,151
category2,124
category1,135
category2,315
```

I would like to create an exclusive unordered list of the categories (no duplicates of the categories), so the list should look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>category1</li>
  <li>category2</li>
</ul>
```

The array is quite big, so it should be fast. 
This is what I have so far (displaying some part of the CSV as scatterplot):

```
  d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Value = +d.Value;
  });

svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 1)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Value); })
  .attr("cy", 10);
```

What’s the best way to create the category list besides the svg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply build another array with the categories:

```
var categories = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Category = Category;
  d.Value = +Value;
  if(categories.indexOf(d.Category) == -1) categories.push(d.Category);
});

// etc

d3.select("body").append("ul").selectAll("li")
  .data(categories)
  .enter().append("li")
  .html(function(d) { return d; });
```

Comment: Using [`d3.set`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_set) instead of `indexOf` will be more efficient.

Comment: `d.Category = Category;` was an error by me and should be removed… Thanks for your help! And `d.Value = +Value;` should be `d.Value = +d.Value;`